# How to dataframe a nested json in python? The json is recursive has same key names that need to be dataframed as a same column

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
 {


"employee":[
      {
         "company":"xxx",
         "address":"yyy",
         "person":[
            {
               "name":"myname",
               "qualifications":"graduate",
               "person":[
                  {
                     "name":"myname2",
                     "qualifications":"graduate2",
                     "person":[
                        {
                           "name":"myname3",
                           "qualifications":"graduate3"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I need to know how to dataframe all similar key's directly to one column.

eg)

| company | address | name | qualifications |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xxx | yyy | myname | graduate |
| xxx | yyy | myname2 | graduate2 |
| xxx | yyy | myname3 | graduate3 |

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
dct = {
    "employee": [
        {
            "company": "xxx",
            "address": "yyy",
            "person": [
                {
                    "name": "myname",
                    "qualifications": "graduate",
                    "person": [
                        {
                            "name": "myname2",
                            "qualifications": "graduate2",
                            "person": [
                                {
                                    "name": "myname3",
                                    "qualifications": "graduate3",
                                }
                            ],
                        }
                    ],
                }
            ],
        }
    ]
}


def get_employees(d, company=None, address=None):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        company = d.get("company", company)
        address = d.get("address", address)

        if "name" in d:
            yield company, address, d["name"], d.get("qualifications")

        yield from get_employees(d.get("person"), company, address)
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for v in d:
            yield from get_employees(v, company, address)


df = pd.DataFrame(
    get_employees(dct["employee"]),
    columns=["company", "address", "name", "qualifications"],
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  company address     name qualifications
0     xxx     yyy   myname       graduate
1     xxx     yyy  myname2      graduate2
2     xxx     yyy  myname3      graduate3
```

Comment: Thank you @Andrej Kesely . i would love to know if there are any direct way to dataframe this instead of iterating?